# what is this mongodb line in english

Tags: mongodb

I'm a mongodb noob trying to learn mongodb...

I'm just tying to understand what this line is saying in english...

```
{ $project : { _id : { $substr : ["$_id",0,1] } } }
```

can someone translate?

Comment: did you try google translate?

Comment: I don't know mongodb but to me it reads as: _"The id of the project is the first caracter of the variable $_id"_

Comment: `$project` is the verb, not the noun, and is a sort of MongoDB query filter; it's a way of modifying the way objects appear in query results.

Comment: @JBernardo that made me laugh +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that in the response to a query being projected through this expression, the `_id` field of each object should be replaced by only the first character of its actual value.  It's part of the aggregation framework, documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project).